# Lubuntu Focal 20.04 slow to start up

Tags: boot, 20.04

It takes several minutes to get to the login screen, which is way slower than Windows 7 on the same machine.  This is a T3500 Xeon machine with 24 GB RAM and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760.  There's a lot of HD activity the entire time.

This is a reasonably fresh install (a few months ago), though I did preserve my home dir during install.  I don't recall it ever starting up as fast as I thought it should after install, but maybe it's also gotten worse over time...

After logging in, everything is very responsive and normal-feeling.

Relevant portion of dmesg below (there's loads of stuff before the 4 second mark that probably isn't relevant).

I notice some "gaps" below in the timing, but I'm not sure how to interpret them.  I'm guessing the messages are posted after each operation completes, so the culprit for the gap goes to the message after the gap.  But what about "audit" messages that appear mid-gap?

```
[    4.388089] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    4.388686]    prefetch64-sse  : 17386 MB/sec
[    4.389336]    generic_sse     : 15151 MB/sec
[    4.389337] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (17386 MB/sec)
[    4.420250] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel, zoned=yes
[    5.112892] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    5.232617] random: crng init done
[    6.776820] systemd[1]: RTC configured in localtime, applying delta of -240 minutes to system time.
[    7.124970] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    7.373179] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.15 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    7.392480] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    7.426090] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <Precision-Workstation-T3500>.
[   10.182570] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[   10.182862] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[   10.183106] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   10.183168] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   10.183344] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   10.183389] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[   10.183405] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   10.183416] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   10.183430] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[   10.183505] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[   10.183602] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[   10.183692] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[   10.183788] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   10.183843] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   10.184032] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   10.184121] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   10.184236] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   10.184469] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   10.184555] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   10.185492] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   10.186419] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[   10.187482] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[   10.188473] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[   10.190013] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[   10.190917] systemd[1]: Starting Availability of block devices...
[   10.258863] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[   10.259807] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[   10.260767] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[   10.260810] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Module drm being skipped.
[   10.351656] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[   10.351719] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
[   10.397206] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   10.398074] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[   10.399077] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[   10.399969] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[   10.401590] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   10.401755] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   10.401904] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[   10.402050] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[   10.402533] systemd[1]: Finished Availability of block devices.
[   10.403086] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[   10.441020] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   10.633273] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   10.719592] systemd-journald[324]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[   11.147230] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   11.197851] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   11.297121] parport_pc 00:02: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[   11.297183] parport0: PC-style at 0x378 (0x778), irq 7, using FIFO [PCSPP,TRISTATE,COMPAT,EPP,ECP]
[   11.392747] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[   11.991584] loop0: detected capacity change from 0 to 457024
[   12.024804] loop1: detected capacity change from 0 to 226912
[   15.056695] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[   15.060198] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 511.
[   15.914047] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module i7core_edac.c controller i7 core #0: DEV 0000:3f:03.0 (INTERRUPT)
[   15.914071] EDAC PCI0: Giving out device to module i7core_edac controller EDAC PCI controller: DEV 0000:3f:03.0 (POLLED)
[   15.914087] EDAC i7core: Driver loaded, 1 memory controller(s) found.
[   16.122274] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.4)
[   16.207716] dell-smbios A80593CE-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492: WMI SMBIOS userspace interface not supported(0), try upgrading to a newer BIOS
[   16.250825] input: Dell WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/PNP0C14:00/wmi_bus/wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00/9DBB5994-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492/input/input14
[   17.513791] kvm: VM_EXIT_LOAD_IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_CTRL does not work properly. Using workaround
[   18.802951] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   19.013917] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   19.244103] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: Disabling MSI
[   19.244112] snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   19.283402] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input15
[   19.283456] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input16
[   19.283508] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input17
[   19.283602] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input18
[   19.283705] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input19
[   19.283754] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input20
[   19.283798] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:03:00.1/sound/card2/input21
[   19.806184] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for AD1984A: line_outs=1 (0x12/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   19.806194] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0x13/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   19.806198] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x11/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   19.806202] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   19.806204] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   19.806207] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x14
[   19.806209] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x15
[   19.823267] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input22
[   19.823319] input: HDA Intel Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input23
[   19.823366] input: HDA Intel Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input24
[   19.823409] input: HDA Intel Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input25
[   22.113084] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   22.687524] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.112:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=706 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.687752] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.112:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=705 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.688712] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.116:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=703 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.776323] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.200:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=704 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.776330] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.200:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=704 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.852963] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.280:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=708 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.939713] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.364:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=710 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.939720] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.364:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=710 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.939723] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.364:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=710 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   22.939726] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979147.364:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" pid=710 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.796959] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   33.796988] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   33.796990] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   33.796993] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   33.796995] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   33.796998] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   35.175252] kauditd_printk_skb: 26 callbacks suppressed
[   35.175255] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979159.600:38): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=894 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[   43.187673] tg3 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   43.187684] tg3 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[   43.187699] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready
[   53.490839] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than 0000:03:00.0 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[   53.490845] caller os_map_kernel_space+0x88/0xd0 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
[   55.317481] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device DVI-I-0
[   82.279865] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979206.048:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=1733 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[   85.717509] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   85.717513] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   85.717517] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  100.693373] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device DVI-I-0
[  101.081318] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device DVI-I-0
[  101.105153] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device DVI-I-0
[  107.384620] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979231.156:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/jasonrohrer/.cache/thumbnails/normal/50fabd4e0e74c10430ce1c69e2c4464b.png" pid=2107 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  107.739468] audit: type=1400 audit(1650979231.508:41): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" name="/home/jasonrohrer/.cache/thumbnails/normal/6d1229cfb0dd90a5343ac369a065843a.png" pid=2111 comm="evince-thumbnai" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  159.909731] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, quota, no debug enabled
[  159.967878] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[  160.018782] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
[  160.101345] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
```

I just booted it up again, and it took 85 seconds from when I pressed ENTER on the GRUB screen until I got to the login screen and could type my password.

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 8.787s
└─multi-user.target @1min 8.787s
  └─mysql.service @24.716s +44.070s
    └─network.target @24.713s
      └─NetworkManager.service @17.814s +6.898s
        └─dbus.service @17.811s
          └─basic.target @17.650s
            └─sockets.target @17.650s
              └─snapd.socket @17.649s +817us
                └─sysinit.target @17.578s
                  └─systemd-timesyncd.service @17.299s +278ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @17.143s +118ms
                      └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.425s +12.716s
                        └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.074s +263ms
                          └─systemd-journald.socket @3.860s
                            └─-.mount @3.857s
                              └─system.slice @3.857s
                                └─-.slice @3.857s
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: Updated with that info!

Comment: Note the third line of your output: `mysql.service @24.716s +44.070s`. Now you know what's taking so long.